# When to show Alert for Startup and coming out of background?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

In my project I show an Alert to the user to indicate an 'empty list'.
Right now, I show it in `AppDelegate>applicationDidBecomeActive`.
I'm doing this because I want the alert to show if the list is empty
at app startup and when coming out of the background (iOS 4.2 through 5.x).

EDIT:

I use a method in the AppDelegate, and call it with a slight delay, and I still get this notice. 
`[self performSelector:@selector(checkForNoMessages) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];`

However, this causes a "wait_fences" notice in the debugger and I'd prefer not to submit to Apple with this notice.

Where is the proper place to put a popup Alert so that it appears:

1) At App startup

AND

2) When the App is coming out of the background?

Do I need the Alert in more than one place?

Comment: try performing the selector( a  new method in which you show alert) after a certain delay in appdidbecomeactive method... and check if the wait_fences still pops up in the console?

Comment: @Shubhank I'm using a slight delay now and I get the notice. I should have mentioned that in the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - the problem wasn't where I called the alert, it was because it was in a method. Once I moved the code from a method into applicationDidBecomeActive, all is well.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend writing a method in your AppDelegate or better in your root view controller which shows the message. Maybe with some arguments, so you can reuse it but that's up to you.

If you are following the MVC architecture ask your model about existing entries and trigger the Alert message if necessary. But encapsulate this behavior in a controller as well.

application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: and  applicationDidBecomeActive: are the places where you want to delegate this task to your controller.

More about iOS Multitasking: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html

Edit:
Don't forget that you have to call the methods from the main thread.
And do all startup stuff first.

Comment: I'm already using a method in the AppDelegate, and calling it with a slight delay and I still get this notice. I'll edit my post to include this info.

Comment: Sorry, could not reproduce the error you get. But I would avoid the approach with delays, this leads to unpredictable behaviour..

Comment: Are you testing with iOS 5.x simulator? Try making a simple method in the delegate that shows an alert, then calling it in applicationDidBecomeActive.

Comment: Using iOS 5.x simulator:- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"test" message:@"test" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

Comment: OK - the problem wasn't where I called the alert, it was because it was in a method. Once I moved the code from a method into applicationDidBecomeActive, all is well.